# How can I execute something whenever a string is in an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to create a swear filter for a Discord bot (using the [Discordie](https://github.com/qeled/discordie) library), and I've tried two scripts (both which don't work properly)

```
var swear = ["swear1", "swear2"]
bot.Dispatcher.on(Event.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
    if (e.message.content == swear) {
        e.message.delete();
    }
```

None of the swear words are blocked in the script, so it's like the script doesn't even exist.

I also tried this:

```
var swear = ["swear1", "swear2"]
bot.Dispatcher.on(Event.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {
        if (vendors[i].e.message.content == swear) {
            found = true;
            e.message.delete();
        }
    }
});
```

Neither of these work, so I'm not sure what to try now. Any suggestions/changes I should make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I'm familiar with vendors with discordie, but a combination of your two approaches might work.

In the first, you're comparing an array to a string, so that'll probably give you problems at the outset. In the second, you use a loop to traverse an array, but the array isn't the right one.

Further, if you did have two strings to compare, you wouldn't want to necessarily check if they were entirely equal, but literally that one string is in another. That function sometimes exists as Contains, but I believe the javascript method is indexOf. This helps because the function should return -1 if the string isn't present.

Consider:

```
var swear = ["swear1", "swear2"]
bot.Dispatcher.on(Event.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
  for(var i = 0; i < swear.length; i++){
    if (e.message.content.indexOf(swear[i]) !== -1) {
      e.message.delete();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the script works, but now I have another problem- other words are being blocked as well. For example, if "old" was added into the script to be delete, then if I said "bold" that would be deleted as well. On top of that, there's an issue with the filter being case sensitive (I can fix that by adding a variety of words with capitals in them, that's not as bad)

Comment: Have you solved this yet? Your solution would be to split the lowercase message by spaces and then loop through each word to check for its existence in the swear list.

Answer (score 0):

Is not working because your are comparing a string to an array. You should check if the string exists as an element in the array. To do that you can use:

```
arrayVar.indexOf(message.content)
```

For more info check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf